# Azure Service Bus - Invalid authorization token signature error for queue creation

Tags: c#, azure, console, azure-servicebus-queues

I have to send message to Queue. I have specified connection string in app.config. I already set SharedAccessKeyName and SharedAccessKey on azure and set in connection string.

I am using below console code to send message.

```
string connString =  ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];
NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connString);


            QueueClient client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connString, "testqueue");
            BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage("test");
            client.Send(message);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I am getting error:

> 40103: Invalid authorization token signature ...

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the connection string? **Please replace account name and key with some dummy values**.

Answer (score 3):

> How to resolve this issue?

According to your mentioned excetpion `Invalid authorization token signature`, I assume the error occured in the connection string.

```
Endpoint=sb://{servicebusName}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={policyName};SharedAccessKey=xxxx";
```

We could get it from the azure portal, more details you could refer to the screenshot. We also could refer to [Get started with Service Bus queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues).

[image]

**Note:** If you use added SAS Policy, please make sure it has access to send message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When generating the SAS token, for example using C#, pass the following:

- resourceUri should be without the trailing '/messages'
- key should be the SharedAccessKey, instead of the full connection string.